# Keystore get alias with Unicode encoding

Tags: unicode, certificate, keystore

When i use C# to get certificate issuer, it returns correctly.
Here is my code:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(mCert.SubjectName.Name);
}
```

Result: C=VN, L=HÀ NỘI, CN=TẬP ĐOÀN VIỄN THÔNG QUÂN ĐỘI (test)...

But in Java, i cannot get alias with Unicode character. 
Here is my code :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, null);

Enumeration e = ks.aliases();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(alias);
}
```

Result is T?P ÐOÀN VI?N THÔNG QUÂN Ð?I (test)

So, how can i get alias Unicode characters in Java like C# ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please ensure this is not just a rendering issue. Print out each character as a number.

Comment: It is not about the render issue. I use System.out.println("TẬP ĐOÀN VIỄN THÔNG QUÂN ĐỘI"); and it render correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6522064 . Is there anyway to fix it?